# Exo Player Progressive Playback

Tags: android, progressive, exoplayer

I want to playback offline playready streams using ExoPlayer , using Downloaded Audio and video **fragments(chunks)**. Even i do have manifest and Quality level of both Streams.Is there a direct support or should i do it by having custom **SampleSource**.
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Hard to understand what the problem is, or what you've done to try and  solve it. Do you have an example of the code you are using? And can you take a little time to explain what your program should do for it's user?

Comment: thanks Charlie , I have made changes i feel one with Android ExoPlayer knowledge will be able to understand this.